# Redirect to SF1 from Action Link Templates

Tags: salesforce1-app, actionlink

I am using [Action Link Template](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/action_link_group_template_design.htm) to redirect my user in sf1. It is working fine in SF1 Simulator and one/one.app. But in the SF1 app it redirect user to Desktop website. is there any way we can move the user into SF1 from here

Answer (score 2):

Action links are a developer feature that can be used to add more complex functionality into Chatter Feed posts in the form of an interactive button. These can be used to take a user to a Web page, initiate a file download, or invoke an API call to Salesforce or an external server.

Currently the Action Link and Action Link Template features are not supported in the Salesforce1 hybrid (downloadable) applications on iOS and Android devices.

Users may see Feed posts where the Action Link button is not displayed or the Action Link does not behave as expected. For example, when navigating to another Visualforce page the navigation does not register that the user is in Salesforce1 and tries to display the full-site version of the page.

Resolution: These features are fully supported for the mobile browser version of Salesforce1 on supported browsers.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though the page you're redirecting to isn't enabled for SF1 mobile. You should also add a tab for the page you're redirecting to for use with SF1. I highly recommend that you visit Trailhead and go through the [Visualforce Mobile Module](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/module/visualforce_mobile_salesforce1).

**Edit**

I found a blog post by @AndrewFawcett titled Using [Action Link Templates to Declaratively call API’s](http://andyinthecloud.com/2015/07/12/using-action-link-templates-to-declaratively-call-apis/) that may be helpful to you in resolving your issue. In it, I noticed this image that relates to the Group Template Edit Overflow Action Edit Options:

[image: Group Template Overflow Action Edit]

Andrew does a great job of explaining how Action Link Templates work and that they also need to have a Group Action Template to encapsulate them as well. He goes into great detail and has some diagnostic tips for use in the Developer Console. I recommend you read his article to see if there's something in your template may not have been configured in the manner necessary to function as expected.

Comment: I already enabled for SF1 and it is working fine in Simulator but not in the downloaded app.

Comment: Do you have SF1 enabled for your users? Have you added the page to SF1 under Mobile Administration>Mobile Navigation: Navigation Menu Items? You may also need to clear your browser cache for the page to show up. Finally, did you add the action to the SF1 Actions Menu?

Comment: Yes i did all these things already. This functionality is working fine in Simulator(/one/one.app).  but not in the downloaded app.

Comment: You may need to clear the cache in your mobile device and it's browser too. Again, I highly recommend the Trailhead Visualforce Mobile Module where you'll encounter some of these same issues as you  make changes to your org.

Comment: I already clear the cache in both places. I also tried Visualforce Mobile Module but i don't think it is related to Action Link Template.

Comment: See my edit with link to @AndrewFawcett blog article.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I already studied about Action Links and How they work. My Problem is simple I am redirect user to custom page from Chatter Action Link it works fine in one/one.app (keep user in SF1) but when i click on these button with SF! downloaded app it breaks the flow and redirect user to desktop site.